# Как загружать большого размера фото в oсStore 3.0.3.7?

Tags: php, opencart, ocstore

не могу понять как снять ограничение загружаемых фотографий в OpenCart 3 (oсStore 3.0.3.7)  То-есть OpenCart лимитирует размер фото до 300 Кб , но как поставить до 1мб ??

Нашел на форумах информацию, что нужно менять эту строку в admin\controller\common\filemanager.php

```
if ($this->request->files['image']['size'] > 300000) {
$json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_file_size');
}
```

Но в версии oсStore 3.0.3.7 нет такой строки. Может кто то подскажет как решить данную проблему??

Answer (score 0):

В этом файле есть такой код:

```
if ($file['size'] > $this->config->get('config_file_max_size')) {
                    $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_filesize');
                }
```

Лимит на размер файла настраивается в панели управления сайтом (админке). В разделе: Система->Настройки->Сервер->Загрузки (Максимальный размер файла).